# Can't compile single jsp's

Tags: jsp, compiler-errors, glassfish-4, netbeans-8

I try compiling single JSP file outside of the `WEB-INF/view` directory at the same level of `index.jsp` for testing purpose but I get this error code:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.netbeans.modules.web.project.ant.JspCSingle

It used to work fine, I could create single JSP files outside the WEB-INF but I have no clue what happened that keeps me from doing it now...

I use Netbeans 8.0.2 and Glassfish 4.1

Comment: see this ..it might help http://forums.netbeans.org/topic38755.html

Answer (score 0):

After doing some [research](https://www.google.com/search?q=Could%20not%20find%20or%20load%20main%20class%20org.netbeans.modules.web.project.ant.JspCSingle&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=cant%20compile%20single%20jsp%20file) I uninstalled and reinstalled Netbeans and it solved the issue for me.